# r8168-dkms build fails on ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: drivers

Hello I have installed 16.04.2 and I am trying to install the realtek driver. I have tried installing it by apt-get, but it fails and exits on starting the compile. Here is the log of the make:

```
  DKMS make.log for r8168-8.041.00 for kernel 4.8.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Thu Feb 16 21:25:44 PST 2017
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic'
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/r8168_n.o
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/r8168_n.c: In function ‘rtl8168_fix_features’:
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/r8168_n.c:4212:30: error: ‘NETIF_F_ALL_CSUM’ undeclared (first use in this function)
                 features &= ~NETIF_F_ALL_CSUM;
                              ^
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/r8168_n.c:4212:30: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/r8168_n.c: In function ‘rtl8168_start_xmit’:
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/r8168_n.c:24599:12: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘trans_start’
         dev->trans_start = jiffies;
            ^
scripts/Makefile.build:289: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/r8168_n.o' failed
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/r8168_n.o] Error 1
Makefile:1491: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build' failed
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic'
```

Any help is appreciated as I have no idea how to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you install this driver?

Comment: I am installing it because I am dual booting and the r8169 driver causes problems on dual boot setups

Comment: It is very unlikely that any driver is related to any dual boot problems.

Comment: No this is a fresh install of 16.04.2 I am using the kernel that came with it by default

Comment: @Pilot6 ah! The yakkety repos have 42. I'll remove my comment. Then your answer is correct. I'll go vote it up.

Comment: Use @Pilot6 answer, it'll fix the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can install a patched for the 4.8 kernel driver from Yakkety this way:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/r8168/r8168-dkms_8.042.00-2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i r8168-dkms_8.042.00-2_all.deb
```

Comment: OP is using 4.8.

Comment: I thought 16.04 came with 4.4. Maybe they changed that in 16.04.2? OP says it came with 4.8. Live and learn.

Comment: 16.04.2 iso has the 4.8 kernel.

Comment: After following @Pilot6 instructions you need to blacklist `r8169` and `mii`. Then you need to go into connections and fiddle with IPv4 (or something like that) and set DHCP to automatic (or something like that) then it works. Sorry Internet Protocol is one of my weak points.

Answer (score 0):

Found a good work arround by installing a module by hand. Just download the module source from here: http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2

Just take the LINUX driver for kernel up to 4.7 which will also work for 4.8 kernels. You can simply start autorun.sh and it will compile and install the kernel module for you ethernet adapter.

Comment: This is not the best way. You will have to re-install it after every kernel upgrade.

Comment: You are right. Worked for me, but now I am using your solution.